# Hi, How can we implement the dropdown buttons in xamarin forms in button click or in label click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, drop-down-menu

For example if we have a button on the mobile screen when we click on that button it will display dropdown menu,in that dropdown,clickable buttons will be displayed.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Button Grid.Column="0" ClassId="Dropdowns" Text="Aktionen" Style="{DynamicResource topActBtnStyle}" FontSize="22" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" xct:SideMenuView.MenuAppearanceType="SlideInOut"/>
                        <RelativeLayout IsVisible="True" Grid.Column="0" ClassId="Dropdowns">
                            <Button Text="Reset" Style="{DynamicResource topActBtnStyle}" FontSize="22" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Button Text="Exit" Style="{DynamicResource topActBtnStyle}" FontSize="22" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Button Text="Logout" Style="{DynamicResource topActBtnStyle}" FontSize="22" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UserNameText}" Style="{DynamicResource topActBtnStyle}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                    </Grid>
```

But all the buttons are displaying at the same place in row.column="0"
i want those buttons in drop down (Reset,Exit,Logout)

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: what i was provided is sample & what i tried it was not working, i want the relevant code in xaml or c#
Could you please help me out.

Comment: Xamarin does not have a native drop down.  You say "all the buttons are displaying at the same place" - if you actually show us what you are doing perhaps we could help you solve that problem

Comment: My guess is that you are looking for it's a [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/)

Comment: I'm not looking for picker, in picker we can select the items only but what i want is when click on the dropdown items it should act like a button click

Comment: i will attach the screenshot by tomorrow beacuse it was taking long time to run the xamarin forms andriod emulator.Actually i kept the XAML code in the post but unfortunately it was not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

> But all the buttons are displaying at the same place in row.column="0"

That's because you used `RelativeLayout`  and didn't set the position for them.

But you can also use `StackLayout` to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<StackLayout> 
        <Grid  RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" ClassId="Dropdowns" Text="Aktionen"  Clicked="Button_Clicked" FontSize="22" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" xct:SideMenuView.MenuAppearanceType="SlideInOut"/>

            <StackLayout x:Name="mStackLayout"  Orientation="Vertical"  IsVisible="false" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" ClassId="Dropdowns" >

                <Button Text="Reset"  FontSize="22" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>

                <Button Text="Exit"  FontSize="22" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>

                <Button Text="Logout"  FontSize="22" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>

            </StackLayout>

            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="UserNameText"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>

        </Grid>
  </StackLayout>
```

And function `Button_Clicked`

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        mStackLayout.IsVisible = !mStackLayout.IsVisible; 
    }
```

Note:

I used `StackLayout`  to achieve this function. Of course, you can also use `RelativeLayout` to achieve it. But for your requirement, I think `StackLayout` is a simpler way.
For more about `RelativeLayout`, you can check [RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout) .

Comment: I will try & let you know its working or not !
Thank you jessie.

Comment: Waiting for your good news. :)

Comment: Its not working jessie 

Comment: Could you please post the code snippets of your app?